# Overriding method of qgis object does not work

Tags: pyqgis

I try to reimplement the `renderDiagram()` method from `QgsHistogramDiagram` to add some labels directly to the diagram (using the position argument).
So far, I tried to set up my own class to override the method:

```
class OwnHistogram(QgsHistogramDiagram):
    def __init__(self):
        super(OwnHistogram, self).__init__()

    def renderDiagram(self, feature, renderContext, diagramSettings, position):
        # Here I want to see if function is entered:
        print('Try to override')
        super(OwnHistogram, self).renderDiagram(
            feature, renderContext, diagramSettings, position)
```

But the function is not entered, while Histogram is shown as if nothing has changed.
Is it not possible to get into the C++-wrapped methods, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!
Overriding functions of the `QgsHistogramDiagram` only works, if there also exists an override of the `clone()` function (similar to other inherited qgis-objects), like:

```
def clone(self):
    return OwnHistogram()
```